# how to assign a const object to be used as a template

Tags: angular, typescript

I am constructing elasticsearch queries and would like to use object templates for building the POST body of the queries, before sending to my data service.

The query builds great the first time, however, as I use the templates, the actual const objects I declared are changed, and the template is broken after that. In the code below, not only is the retunQuery value changed, but the value of the INIT_QUERY const is changed the same. How can I use this const object as a template, without actually changing it's value.

```
const INIT_QUERY = {
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "filter": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": <any>[]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

const MATCH_QUERY = {
    "match": <any>{}
}
...

export class QueryBuilder {

 constructor() {}

 buildQuery() {
   let returnQuery = INIT_QUERY;
   .... loop

     let query = MATCH_QUERY;
     query.match[dbfield].query = 'fieldValueToSearch';

     returnQuery.query.filtered.filter.bool.must.push(query);

   .... end loop

   return returnQuery;
 }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`let returnQuery = INIT_QUERY;` just creates another reference to `INIT_QUERY`. Both refer to the same object.

`Object.assign({}, INIT_QUERY);` will only create a shallow copy, so it won't be enough.

The easiest way I see is to provide your "template" as JSON and create new objects from that.

This will break intellisense though. You will need to create an interface and do a type cast.

```
interface Query {
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": any[]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
const INIT_QUERY = `{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
        "filter": {
            "bool": {
                "must": []
            }
        }
    }
}`;
let query: Query = <Query>JSON.parse(INIT_QUERY);
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what the interface would look like in this case?

Comment: Sure, I edited my answer. It's just the structure of your object.